# How to add a table into the TOC in a Python script?

Tags: arcpy, table, display

I recently experienced some troubles in adding a table from a specific folder to the TOC using a Python script.
Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: can you better explain your issue? the better your question, the better your answers.

Comment: my problem is that, using a python script, I'd like to add a table view to the TOC once created because I found that evenif the script creates the tableView in the workspace folder, the same table is not autmatically added to the TOC and other operations on the table cannot be performed. Moreover I have the ArcGIS 10.0 version, so I cannot use the command arcpy.mapping.AddTableView, as correctly suggested by @artwork21.. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what error you may be getting, but in general you can use [arcpy.mapping.AddTableView](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000017000000) to add a standalone table into ArcMap TOC.

Comment: @AnnalisaMinelli AddTableView will only be available if you are using ArcGIS 10.1 or later

Comment: thanks to artwork21 and PolyGeo. My problem was exactly this: I got only ArcGIS 10.0. No way to do this in that version?